# How to have x axis in ggplot display correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is some sample code. There are no errors but am wanting to know what I would do so that it displays the data from left to right according to the month1 values. 201812 (december 2018) being the left most and 202011 (November 2020) being the right most.

```
 #Data generation
 Month1 <- c(201812,20191,20192,20193,20194,20195,20196,
        20197,20198,20199,201910,201911,201912,20201
        ,20202,20203,20204,20205,20206,20207
        ,20208,20209,202010,202011)
 annualjobgrowth<- c(44400,46000,42600,40500,42800,40500,36000,
                34000,32300,29900,21900,24500,21000,
                23300,16000,-6200,-275600,-249500,-149200,
                -136500,-129900,-122800,-113900,-109500)
  Rate <- 
  c(3.3,3.4,3.1,3.0,3.1,2.9,2.6,2.5,2.3,2.1,1.6,1.7,1.5,1.7,1.1,-0.4,
-19.5,-17.6,-10.5,-9.6,-9.1,-8.6,-8.0,-7.7)
cesyoy <- data.frame(Month1,annualjobgrowth, Rate)

  #Chart
  library(ggplot2)

  ceschart <- ggplot() + geom_col(data = cesyoy, aes(x = Month1, y = annualjobgrowth))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works better if you make proper Date value in R rather than using these numeric code. For example

```
library(dplyr)
cesyoy %>% 
  mutate(year = substr(as.character(Month1),1,4),
         month = substr(as.character(Month1),5, 7),
         trdate = as.Date(paste(year,month,"1", sep="-"))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_col(aes(x = trdate, y = annualjobgrowth))
```

[image]

Comment: getting a bizaare error "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous"

Comment: @TimWilcox I've tried changing the name of the variable in the mutate. But even with both of them being `date` it should have worked fine. Did you copy/paste what I had exactly?

Comment: not sure what happened but when I re-copy and pasted, the error went away. Anyways, thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

We could also pad 0 after the 4-digit and convert to `Date` based on the number of digits in the 'Month1' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
cesyoy %>% 
     mutate(Month1 = ymd(str_replace(Month1, "^(....)(.$)" , 
               "\\10\\2"), truncated = 2)) %>% 
     ggplot() + 
        geom_col(aes(x = Month1, y = annualjobgrowth))
```

-output

[image]